# Embedding resource using script

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, embedded-resource

I have to create library/support application file with 1000s of sound files (total size around 1GB). For that I am planning to use following code:

```
package Resources.questions
{
    public class HindiVoice
    {
        [Embed(source="1.mp3",symbol="c1")]
        private static const c1:Class;
        [Embed(source="2.mp3",symbol="c2")]
        private static const c2:Class;
        //To-Do add 1000 files with symbol definition
        public function HindiVoice()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Above file is hard to maintain. Can I use "for loop" to iterate from 1 to 1000 and embed sound files in the project? I am using flash developer 4.7.

Actually if some object is there that allows metadata addition would be helping in this effort the pseudo code would be like:

```
public function Hindi()
        {
            for(var i=3;i<=1000;i++){
                var o = new <some object for metadata embed> "@[embed(source='" +i +".mp3',symbol='c"+i+"')]";
                this.addChild(o);

            }
        }
```

Comment: No but nothing is stopping you from creating a little app that does that for you. A simple little AIR app could iterate the files in a folder and output a class file with all assets embedded correctly. I do that all the time. Also note that sound files don't have to be embedded, they play just fine when loaded externally.

Comment: we need to embed files to avoid possibility of piracy. Iteration of file is fine but how to embed in a way that we do not need to supply mp3 files in the package, allowing us to access embedded file from main application?

Comment: you can't embed and not have the sound files be part of the package. What are you trying to prevent?

Comment: If I remove audio folder from package file, at run time files are not available. To avoid packaging audio folder I need to embed all files. Doing via code will increase the maintainability of the code.

Comment: I am able to embed as I explained in my question body, but not able to make it maintainable as I may need to add/delete some files. Embedding is the client's requirement.

Comment: if you embed then the files are packaged with the app, no way around it. I think you are misunderstanding how embed works. Embed does reference the physical file path, they have to be there.

Answer (score 0):

It seems flex do not support embedding of large files. My attempt to embed large size files resulted into application closing without warning (found this behaviour in design time did not test with compilation).

I did not go ahead with embedding but possible ways could be:
1) Have a password protected zip file with the assets.
2) Use other tool like java for encapsulation with contract code to access file from there.